# Convert POSIX time to Joda time in Java

Tags: datetime, posix, jodatime

What is the most accurate way of convering a POSIX timestamp like `1401793903.3493562` (Double or String) to a Joda `DateTime` object in Java.

POSIX time is a number of seconds since 1970-01-01, i.e. the above number corresponds to (python): `datetime.fromtimestamp(1401793903.3493562)` => `datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 13, 11, 43, 349356)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to converts to millis and use constructor `DateTime(long)`

```
  double posixTimestamp = 1401793903.3493562;
  long millis = (long) posixTimestamp * 1000;
  DateTime date = new DateTime(millis);
```

Comment: This is POSIX time -- it is the number of seconds since epoch. The above value is actually for today. So your suggestion will not work.

Comment: @OlegS. what is number before dot and what is number after dot in your format? As I understand, number of seconds is before dot, but what is after dot?

Comment: In C and Linux POSIX time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 and a fraction of a second after the dot. Most closely the above number corresponds to Java mills representation, which would be 1401793903349356. What you get for the above number is (python): `datetime.fromtimestamp(1401793903.3493562)` => `datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 13, 11, 43, 349356)`

Comment: That would the solution I was thinking about and the only thing that bothers me is the loss of precision. Obviously I cannot do better than mills in Java (at least in Joda), but I was not sure if in the process of converting this double to long I would loose further precision. Looks like not, so looks like no need to use `BigDecimal` as suggested elsewhere. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on your use case, and also what type you're starting with.  If you get the value as a String, use `BigDecimal` to maintain precision.  If you start off with a `double`, you've already lost any precision you might care about, so the current answer doesn't hurt you any.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [constructor of DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29). It takes the milliseconds since UNIX epoch without counting leapseconds, so it is almost the same as a POSIX timestamp. The only difference is the factor of 1000 to transform seconds to milliseconds. My proposal (the use of String instead of double can sometimes be more precise):

```
double timestamp = 1401793903.3493562; // in seconds
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(timestamp);

// transform to milliseconds
bd = bd.multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

// create Joda object
DateTime dt = new DateTime(bd.longValue());

System.out.println(bd); // 1401793903349
System.out.println(dt); // 2014-06-03T13:11:43.349+02:00 (in my timezone)
```

Comment: What is the actual benefit of using `BigDecimal` here or of using `String` for the initial representation if double can hold 15 digits, which (at least for the next tens of years) is better than the millisecond precision offered by Java. At some point POSIX timestamp will become less accurate than long milliseconds, but that is still about a century from now :)

Comment: @OlegS. That is a valid point. `double` is probably sufficient although I am not completely sure about it for EVERY timestamp (double cannot represent some values correctly). First I only saw your wish for "most accurate way" and an answer based on `SimpleDateFormat`, so my answer was a quick reaction (and at least not wrong).

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, so +1. POSIX time is normally given back in C or python as a double value, so there is little point to improve beyond that. The conversion to long I was thinking would be an issue, but it actually is not as multiplying by 1e3 does not change the significance of the double representation. Otherwise, as I say right now POSIX times are much more accurate than Joda millis-based, by 4 orders of magnitude, but this changes as time goes by

Comment: @OlegS. Remember that `double` is a floating number. Test for example the value `0.1d` versus `"0.1"`. You will see a slight difference in far fraction part (if you use timestamps with such fine-granular fractions).

Comment: Sure, but being 4 orders of magnitude more accurate (now) than the Java millis representation I can probably sacrifice the last digit without affecting the result, can I?

Comment: @OlegS. Seems so. For new time library in Java 8 (with nanosecond precision) this might be another story.